# "The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context" for .aspx page ONLY

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an issue I can not, for the life of me, figure out.

We have an MVC4 app and on a (in fact now I believe it's the only) remaining .aspx page, there is an error in the master page: `The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context`

The line in question is this one: `<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Library") %>`

This bundle is referenced successfully on every other page. To make matters worse, this issue only happens in production (works fine on my local machine, dev server and UAT server). We've only just added bundling to the project, so obviously this issue didn't come up before our latest release.

I have done some googling (a fairly drastic understatement), but can't seem to find the answer.

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope :).

Comment: Compare the file-system of the live server with the file-system of your local server. Compare any possible routing rules and check whether the resource is there in your live version as well. Comparing is the key of balance, if you do so, the force might be with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure

```
 <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
```

is in the web.config. This is needed in order to use the Scripts helper.

Comment: I did check this...but obviously I looked at not-the-production `web.config`. It was missing from production - no idea why, but it was. Thanks!